# How to get Latency, Rendering time using Webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to get the values of latency and rendering time of the web application using Webdriver sampler in jmeter

Could you please tell me how to get those values and if you provide some sample webdriver sampler codes for get rendering time and latency values ..

Expected results:

1)Get latency
2)Get rendering time

Answer (score 0):

You can get latency from the [Performance Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings), something like:

```
def now = System.currentTimeMillis()
def ttfb = WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.performance.timing.responseStart') as long
WDS.sampleResult.setLatency(now - ttfb)
```

I'm not sure what do you mean by "rendering time", the whole WebDriver Sampler execution time is stored as Elapsed Time and it's possible to overwrite it with your own value using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) but you need to let us know what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. i have followed your steps. I got ttfb value. Ttfb value like 1686228861999 i need to convert into milli second for example(4678 ms) could you please help me out

Comment: Have you tried to read remaining 2 lines of the code snippet in my response?

Comment: Yeah it works fine.. could you please give me latency formulas and rendering time application starts load the DOM and complete and readies the DOM.. could you please tell how to code for rendering time